# How to use string slicing inside string.format

Tags: python

How can I do variable string slicing inside `string.format` like this.

```
"{0[:2]} Some text {0[2:4]} some text".format("123456")
```

Result I want result like this.

> 12 Some text 34 some text

Comment: why dont simple `"Some text {0} some text".format("123456"[2:4])`?

Comment: Please see the edit. Actual final string is bit complex.

Comment: [I think you can't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14072884/7222134)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Best you can do is limit how many characters of a string are printed (roughly equivalent to specifying a slice end), but you can't specify arbitrary start or end indices.

Save the data to a named variable and pass the slices to the `format` method, it's more readable, more intuitive, and easier for the parser to identify errors when they occur:

```
mystr = "123456"
"{} Some text {} some text".format(mystr[:2], mystr[2:4])
```

You could move some of the work from that to the format string if you really wanted to, but it's not a huge improvement (and in fact, involves larger temporaries when a slice ends up being needed anyway):

```
"{:.2s} Some text {:.2s} some text".format(mystr, mystr[2:])
```