# Can I use slicing in Template string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following works:

```
from string import Template
d = { "test" : "1234" }
t = "This is a test: ${test}"
s = Template(t).safe_substitute(d)
print(s)
```

Output:

> This is a test: 1234

However, what if I only want `This is a test: 12` in the output? Can I somehow combine template string substitution and slicing?

If I change `t` to `"This is a test: ${test}[:2]"` it prints:

> This is a test: 1234[:2]

And if I change `t` to `"This is a test: ${test[:2]}"` it prints:

> This is a test: ${test[:2]}

I'm not sure if I can use `str.format`, since both the string and the dict are loaded dynamically from files.

I cannot use `f`-strings, because I need to be Python 3.4 compatible.

Comment: u can try `Template(t).safe_substitute(d)[:-2]`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072810/slicing-strings-in-str-format

Comment: @Shijith True for this specific case, but it will not work if the substitution has to be done somewhere in the middle of the template string.

Comment: @MikeScotty How about a duplicate dictionary. `s=Template(t).safe_substitute({key:val[:2] for key,val in d.items()})` ? Although, not much efficient when the no of buckets are more and doing it everytime.

Comment: It should be possible to subclass `string.Template` and make this work. Maybe use `ast.parse` to parse the slice syntax. But I suspect it's less work to upgrade to a version of python that support f-strings instead. 3.4 has reached end of life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can't do it directly in the `Template` string. 
One solution that you could try is to effectively do any string formatting before you template, by using a formatting dictionary and then combining them.

```
from string import Template
d = { "test" : "1234" }
format_dict = {"test": "{:2.2}"}
t = "This is a test: ${test}"
s = Template(t).safe_substitute({k: v.format(d[k]) for k, v in format_dict.items()})
print(s)
```

Output:

> This is a test: 12

**EDIT:** Per @Jon Clements comment you can make this work so you only need specify formatting for some values.

```
from string import Template
d = { "test" : "1234" }
format_dict = {"test": "{:2.2}"}
t = "This is a test: ${test}"
formatted = {k: str.format(format_dict.get(k, '{}'), v) 
             for k, v in d.items()}
s = Template(t).safe_substitute(formatted)
print(s)
```

Comment: I like this idea... it does seem to require you to specify a format for every possible item though... you can re-work it to be something like: `{k: format(v, format_dict.get(k, '')) for k, v in d.iteritems()}` instead... that means you'll get all items available from `d` with their default `str()` formatting, unless you specify otherwise, instead of only items that exist in `format_dict`...

Comment: Nice work-around. It requires you to have a separate dict for formatting, but I can live with that.