# Format string with substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format, substring

I need to format a string with substrings of a variable. If I do:

```
sample="1234567890XXXX"
f"{sample[:5]}/{sample[5:10]}/{sample}/config"
```

It works fine:

```
'12345/67890/1234567890XXXX/config'
```

But if I use format:

```
"{sample[:5]}/{sample[5:10]}/{sample}/config".format(sample="1234567890XXXX")
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```

Any way to make it work with a `format`?

EDIT: just to clarify some things. The format string is passed through a command line argument and the format arguments automatically extracted from a pandas dataframe (as a dict). So, I do not thing the propsed solutions (`f-strings` and extra format arguments) will work.

```
args.out_path.format(**name)
```

Comment: Slice the strings and pass the slices as multiple arguments to `format`: `"{s1}/{s2}/{sample}/config".format(sample="1234567890XXXX", s1={sample[:5]}, s2={sample[5:10]})`

Comment: What's wrong with using f-string, which is way more readble?

Comment: Because i want the format string to be passed as a command line argument, so I don't think the f-string will work. And neither will multiple arguments to format.

Answer (score 1):

As @pho suggested you can supply the slices to str.format():

```
"{s1}/{s2}/{sample}/config".format(sample="1234567890XXXX", s1=sample[:5], s2=sample[5:10])

#output
'12345/67890/1234567890XXXX/config'
```

Python `f-strings` are very different from `str.format()` templates.  Python `f-strings` support slicing and don't use a **"mini-language"** like the formatter. The full power of a python expression is available within each curly-brace of an `f-string`.

> “Format specifications” are used within replacement fields contained within a format string to define how individual values are presented (see Format String Syntax and Formatted string literals). They can also be passed directly to the built-in format() function. Each formattable type may define how the format specification is to be interpreted.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

---

> No, slicing is not supported by builtin str formatting. Although, there is a workaround in case f-strings (runtime evaluated) don't fit your needs.

> You can use a run-time evaluated "f" string. Python f-strings support slicing and don't use a "mini-language" like the formatter.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62024873/13086128

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49884004/13086128

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you're using .format() function's syntax incorrectly.

The correct syntax is

```py
<string>.format(<definition1>,<definition2>,...)
```

for your problem

```py
sample = "1234567890XXXX"
x = "{s1}/{s2}/{sample}/config".format(s1=sample[:5], s2=sample[5:10], sample=sample)
print(x)
```

this gives the output:

```
12345/67890/1234567890XXXX/config
```

just as you desire...
I hope you understood this, thank you.